# Autotag for libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I have been using Windward Auto-tag with my Microsoft Office to tag fields and  generate report using XML files.Can sum1 here please suggest me an alternate software for the same so that i can use  it with libreoffice on my Ubuntu Desktop and work accordingly.

Your suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JODReports (open source) and Docmosis (commercial) work similarly with documents as templates.   Both allow you to use Word or Writer documents as templates and can work on Ubuntu.  Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.